# Any good resources on Data Structures and Algorithms in Haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, data-structures

Is there any one book or blog which can cover the data structures and Algorithms in Haskell with example like

```
------- Data Structures -------
Data.Array 
Data.Bits 
Data.Either 
Data.Graph 
Data.Graph.Inductive 
Data.HashTable 
Data.IntMap 
Data.IntSet 
Data.IORef 
Data.Ix 
Data.Lists 
Data.Map 
Data.Maybe 
Data.Monoid 
Data.PackedString 
Data.Queue 
Data.Ratio 
Data.Set 
Data.STRef 
Data.Tree 
Data.Tuple
Data.Typeable
Data.Unique
Data.Word
-- How to generate Co-Data Structures?
```

```
------- Algorithms -------
Recursive.
Dynamic programming.
Backtracking.
Divide and conquer.
Greedy algorithm.
Probabilistic algorithm.
Randomized algorithm.
```

Below are the few good resources I found on Google.

**Containers** - https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/haskell-containers/latest/haskell-containers.pdf.

**Elementary Data Structures** - http://static.latexstudio.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/elementary-algorithms.pdf

**Chris Okasaki Purely Functional Data structures** - https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/Functional%20Programming/Chris_Okasaki-Purely_Functional_Data_Structures-Cambridge_University_Press%281998%29.pdf

Comment: Okasaki is the most famous resource on this topic at least, and from the little I've read of it it seems deserving -- very clear and insightful.

Comment: Although many of the data structures in your list are quite trivial, if you just go read the source.  For the nontrivial ones, the standard documentation will usually have a link or reference to the paper that it is based on.